# RequireJS: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] when loading asynchronously

Tags: javascript, requirejs, fs

So I'm trying to use RequireJS in my project, but just putting `require('fs')` brings up an error about how it hasn't been loaded yet. On the RequireJS website, it says that the following code should be used instead:

```
require(['fs'], function (fs) {
  //fs is now loaded.
});
```

However, when I use this code, I get the error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]` which says that I should be using a string as an argument to require, but RequireJS says that this does not work.

Would appreciate it if anybody could give me any tips on how to get this working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html), you need something like that.

```js
const requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
    //function to requirejs so that node modules
    //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['fs'], function (fs) {
    console.log('fs is now loaded.');
});
```

Of course, you need to install it first:

```
npm install requirejs
```